# I am trying to get the selected value from a dropdown list using jquery. For some reason, the option selected is not printing to the console. Helppss

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery, and javascript. I am trying to make a tip calculator using jquery, showing one page at a time. I am up to the page where it asks the user how many people users need to input the number in their party.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".begin").click(function(){
    $(".container").html("
      <h1 class = 'jumbotron'>How Many People Ate?</h1>
        <select class='form-control' id= 'foo'>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
       </select>");
    $(".container").append("
      <button class = 'btn btn-info next center-block'>
        Next
      </button>")
  });

  $(".next").click(function(){
    console.log($( "select#foo" ).val());});
  })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Since your buttons are dynamically created, you'll have to use **event delegation** like this:

```
$(".container").on("click", ".next", function(){
    console.log($( "select#foo" ).val());});
});
```

Read more [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) & [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you missed some semicolons there (;)

**My answer:**
You must bind the click event to .container, not the button .next itself to be work :)

change the last script to be like this:

```
$(".container").on('click','.next',function() {
    console.log($( "select#foo" ).val());
});
```

so the full script will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".begin").on('click',function(){
        $(".container").html("
           <h1 class = 'jumbotron'>How Many People Ate?</h1>
           <select class='form-control' id= 'foo'>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
           </select>");
        $(".container").append("
            <button class = 'btn btn-info next center-block'>Next</button>
        ");
    });
    $(".container").on('click','.next',function() {
        console.log($( "select#foo" ).val());
    });
});
```